# Deploying .war in debug mode fails with an error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, deployment, jboss

Deploying `.war` in debug mode fails with below error!! 
It works fine in nornalt. Run mode is STS.

Stack Trace:

```
10:30:06,715 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
10:30:07,718 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
10:30:07,802 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" starting
10:30:09,707 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment shoppingcart-app.war
10:30:10,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment shoppingcart.war
10:30:10,148 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found shoppingcart-app.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called shoppingcart-app.war.dodeploy
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem yesterday.

After doing some searches on the Internet I found the following solution that worked for me:

Open the /standalone/configuration/standalone.xml file from the jboss directory with a text editor and change the following code

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
</subsystem>
```

by adding the *deployment-timeout="1000"* attribute to the *deployment-scanner* tag

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="1000"/>
</subsystem>
```